# Scrapy Rules - Navigating one page at a time

Tags: scrapy

My scrapy script has rules specified as below:

`rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=<xpath for next page>), callback=parse_website, follow= True, ),)`

The website itself has a navigation but each page only shows the link to the next page. i.e as page 1 loads, I can get the link to page 2 and so on and so forth.

How do I get my spider to navigate through all of the n pages?

Thank you!

Comment: Is the next page link always on the same XPath? If so, shouldn't it work with the `rules` you already have?

Comment: It's the same xpath everytime. However rules isn't picking up the second page. Is it supposed to work that way? From my research, I didn't think so

Comment: If `follow` parameter of `Rule` is set to `True`, it should work that way. At least that is my understanding of the [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules).

Comment: Yes, my spider goes to page 2 based on rules but  then stops. It doesn't navigate further into page 3 because I'm guessing rules isn't checked in page 2

Comment: It would be much easier to debug if you posted complete spider code.